Why regex searching second group from the end?
I have a search in app and use regex to highlight found matches. But I notice sometimes it match kinda incorrectly (?).
For example, the regex (case insensitive): (the).*(te). And result for test phrase will be (tested here):

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.

If you take a look at test phrase, it contain a lot of te parts before the last one. Feels like it searching from the end of the line. But I expect it should be like this:

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.

I need it to find the first occurrence. Since in app it's user entered query, I don't know exactly what the regex will be. But it has a pattern: (word1).*(word2).*(word3).
What am I doing wrong? The regex is not correct or it's just a way of it's working?

Change the greedy quantifier .* to the reluctant quantifier .*?:
the.*?te

Notice also that you don't need the grouping brackets.
See live demo.

It helped, thank you!
Btw, grouping needed not for search, it's needed me to know which part of string to highlight (with java.util.regex.Pattern.Matcher I could get the start/end of each group)
